# Как получить элемент со списка, если при нажатии любой клавиши он исчезает?

Tags: python, html, selenium

Мне нужно получить данные о кнопках со списка, но, когда я пытаюсь открыть их через код элемента, список закрывается и их код исчезает из HTML.

Как мне найти хотя бы какие-то идентефикаторы этих кнопок, чтобы в будущем можно было выбрать их с помощью Selenium на Python?

Если вы не поняли проблемы с моего описания, посмотрите, пожалуйста, видеозапись https://youtu.be/4EA1WKDSQRA

Comment: А зачем выбирать если можно написать?

Comment: имел ввиду, чтобы селениум сам выбирал в будущем

Answer (score 0):

Ссылку бы на страницу, на которой это нужно найти, предполагаю, что там в стилях нужно покопаться, что-то вроде display block поискать и галочку снять. на видео очень плохо видно шрифт, едва название класса разбираешь.

Comment: ссылку не смогу дать, ибо для этого нужно регистрироваться в Вконтакте

Comment: Ну, я бы изучил класс vkc_Select_values (если правильно разобрал его на видео), но это предположение только, сложно что-то конкретное сказать без ссылки

Comment: пробовал искать - пишет, что его не существует..

Comment: `.vkc__Select__values{width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;background-color:#fff;background-color:var(--white);-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.12);border:var(--border);border-top:0;-webkit-border-radius:0 0 8px 8px;-webkit-border-radius:0 0 var(--border-radius) var(--border-radius);-moz-border-radius:0 0 8px 8px;-moz-border-radius:0 0 var(--border-radius) var(--border-radius);border-radius:0 0 8px 8px;border-radius:0 0 var(--border-radius) var(--border-radius);max-height:132px;z-index:2}`

Comment: поискал в файле с css, но что здесь можно сделать не нашёл

Comment: Ну, я не знаю, нужно смотреть, может что-то в классах родительского элемента есть или может скриптами как-то это организовано, без живого примера сложно что-то сказать... Можно попробовать overflow:hidden на overflow:visible изменить, возможно в этом загвоздка, но не имея живого примера сложно что-то утверждать.